# redirecting to another domain with AWS lambda whilst keeping the path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, http-redirect

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/redirection-in-a-serverless-api-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/ talks about how to do HTTP 301/302 redirects with AWS Lambda but it doesn't seem to discuss how to do the redirect whilst preserving the path.

Here's the code that they provide:

```
// Returns 302 or 301
var err = new Error("HandlerDemo.ResponseFound Redirection: Resource found elsewhere");
err.name = "http://a-different-uri";
context.done(err, {});
```

Instead of directing requests from http://oldwebsite.com/aaa to http://newwebsite.com/ I'd like to direct them to http://newwebsite.com/aaa.

Any ideas as to how I might do that?

Comment: I'd expect the path to be available in the [event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event) that the Lambda function is invoked with.

Comment: Have you simply tried to return http:///newwebsite.com/aaa as location?

Comment: @MarcC - I only want them to be redirected to http:///newwebsite.com/aaa if and only if they try to visit http:///oldwebsite.com/aaa. If they visit http:///oldwebsite.com/bbb I want them to be redirected to http:///newwebsite.com/bbb

Comment: Well you just have to split the URL into a domain name and resource path. Then return http:///newwebsite/resource-path

Comment: @MarcC - obviously. The question is how do I get the requesting URL. Per the link that jarmod shared (specifically, a [github link at the bottom](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/nodejs-apig/function/index.js)), you have to add a significant amount of boiler plate to get that extra parameter. Which is a bit disappointing. Seems like all you ought to be able to do is just add one extra line vs having to add 20 extra lines to get it to work but whatever.

Comment: Try the [URL class](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) you should succeed with 2-3 lines (one import and one or two statements).

Comment: @MarcC - the URL class tells you how to parse a string that is a URL into it's various constituent components but how do you get that string in the first place? I mean, sure, your answer addresses one part of the "puzzle" but it not the only piece of the puzzle. You have to get the requesting URL and then parse it. But how do you get the requesting URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked a quick test, reusing the approach in the article:

- a REST API,
- a Lambda returning an error,
- an integration transforming the error into an HTTP redirect.

The requested path comes in the `event.path` attribute, so the example requires only minor updates:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const path = event?.path;
    var err = new Error('CustomError');
    err.name = 'http://newwebsite.com' + path;
    throw err;
};
```

A a side note, an HTTP API is probably a better fit for a systematic redirect.
In this case the path is coming through another attribute (ie. `event.rawPath`) and the Lambda result will look more like an HTTP response.